# Get details of an item clicked in a listview in next activity

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

Hi i am working on a code in which in a listview it shows up some details like name and price , which comes from MySQL database . Now when I want to click on that particular item in that listview, what i want is that I want to move in to next activity the layout to which will be the same , only the data keeps changing when an item is clicked.

Like when I click on the Name A , i want to open a new activity in whcih the name as well as its address pincode , phone number will be shown up in details .

I have fetched all the details in the lsitview and shown up some which i want  there and the next are passed to the detailed activity .
But i am not getting any values there in the next activity. 
Please look at the code I have written.

Activity with listview

```
public class Plumbers extends Activity {
    String myJSON;

    public static final String TAG_RESULTS="result";
    public static final String TAG_NAME = "Name";
    public static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "Address";
    public static final String TAG_PINCODE = "Pincode";
    public static final String TAG_PHONENUMBER = "Phone_Number";
    public static final String TAG_DOB = "DOB";
    public static final String TAG_AADHARNUMBER = "Aadhar_Number";
    public static final String TAG_Price = "price";
    public static final String TAG_Spl = "spl";

    JSONArray peoples = null;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> personList;

    ListView list;
    EditText search;
    Spinner spin;

    protected Object adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
        spin=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        search = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.search);
        personList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        getData();
    }

    protected void showList(){
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
            peoples = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);

            for(int i=0;i<peoples.length();i++){
                JSONObject c = peoples.getJSONObject(i);

                String Name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                String price = c.getString(TAG_Price);
                String spl = c.getString(TAG_Spl);

                HashMap<String,String> plumbers = new HashMap<String,String>();
                plumbers.put(TAG_NAME,Name);
                plumbers.put(TAG_Price,price);
                plumbers.put(TAG_Spl,spl);

                personList.add(plumbers);
            }

            final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    Plumbers.this, personList, R.layout.plumber,
                    new String[]{TAG_NAME ,TAG_Spl,TAG_Price },
                    new int[]{R.id.Name , R.id.spl ,R.id.price}
            );

            list.setAdapter(adapter);
            list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,  View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    adapter.getItem(position);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Plumbers.this, Plumber1.class);
                    intent.putExtra("Name", TAG_NAME);
                    intent.putExtra("Address", TAG_ADDRESS);
                    intent.putExtra("Pincode", TAG_PINCODE);
                    intent.putExtra("Phone_Number", TAG_PHONENUMBER);

                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            spin.setAdapter((SpinnerAdapter) adapter);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void getData(){
        class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new   BasicHttpParams());
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.2.7/homerun/plumbers.php");

                // Depends on your web service
                httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

                InputStream inputStream = null;
                String result = null;
                try {
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                    inputStream = entity.getContent();
                    // json is UTF-8 by default
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    result = sb.toString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Oops
                }
                finally {
                    try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
                }
                return result;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result){
                myJSON=result;
                showList();
            }
        }

        GetDataJSON g = new GetDataJSON();
        g.execute();
    }
}
```

Activity for next Details of an item

```
public class Plumber1 extends Activity { 
    ImageView img,call;
    TextView pl1,nm,ad,phn,qu,pin;
    String  Name,Address,Pincode,Phone_Number;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.plumber1);
        img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imag);
        call=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.call);
        pl1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.pl1);
        nm=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
        ad=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Address);
        pin=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Pincode);
        phn=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.phn);
        qu=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.quotation);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (intent.getExtras() != null) {

        Name = intent.getStringExtra("Name");
         Address = intent.getStringExtra("Address");
         Pincode = intent.getStringExtra("Pincode");
         Phone_Number = intent.getStringExtra("Phone_Number");
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  Name + "" + Address + "" + Pincode + "" + Phone_Number +"" ,  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

        nm.setText(Name+"");
    ad.setText(Address+"");
    pin.setText(Pincode+"");
    phn.setText(Phone_Number+"");
        call.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent in = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri
                        .parse("tel:+918058706096"));
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Php file

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");  
    mysql_select_db("homerun");  
    $sql="select * from plumbers WHERE Status = '1'  GROUP BY price  ORDER BY  name ASC" ;  
    $res = mysql_query($sql);
    $result = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
        array_push($result,
        array('Name'=>$row[1],'spl'=>$row[8],'price'=>$row[7]));
    }

    echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));

    mysql_close();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing one thing wrong. When you are passing the intent you are just giving 2 constants and not the actual values you want to pass.

```
intent.putExtra("Name", TAG_NAME);
intent.putExtra("Address", TAG_ADDRESS);
intent.putExtra("Pincode", TAG_PINCODE);
intent.putExtra("Phone_Number", TAG_PHONENUMBER);
```

This Should be something like:

```
MyObject myObj = adapter.getItem(position);
Intent intent = new Intent(Plumbers.this, Plumber1.class);
intent.putExtra(TAG_NAME, myObj.getName());
intent.putExtra(TAG_ADDRESS, myObj.getAdress());
intent.putExtra(TAG_PINCODE, myObj.getPinCode());
intent.putExtra(TAG_PHONENUMBER, myObj.getPhoneNumber());
```

And in your second activity:

```
String name = intent.getStringExtra(TAG_NAME);
String adress = intent.getStringExtra(TAG_ADRESS);
String pincode = intent.getStringExtra(TAG_PINCODE);
String phonenumber = intent.getStringExtra(TAG_PHONENUMBER);
```

Basically atm you are passing 2 constants, instead of the actual information of the object selected. For example, here:

```
 intent.putExtra("Name", TAG_NAME);
```

You are passing a String identified with the key "Name" and it's content is defined like this as static. This is wrong.

```
 public static final String TAG_NAME = "Name";
```

So basically you are getting "Name" from

```
 String name = intent.getStringExtra(TAG_NAME);
```

Hope I made myself understandable.

Answer (score 0):

I beleive you have used values instead of the key when retrieving the intent extra. That is for example instead of:-

```
intent.putExtra("Name", TAG_NAME);
...
String  Name = intent.getStringExtra("TAG_NAME");
```

you should have :-

```
intent.putExtra("Name", TAG_NAME);
...
String  Name = intent.getStringExtra("Name");
```

That is, when setting/putting the **intent extra** the first parameter is the **key** (variable name), the second argument is the **value**. When retrieving you ask for the **key** and the **value** is obtained/returned.

In response to comment:-

> Thanks for the reply ... i have changed the code according to what you
>   said but now i am getting only the key , whether in settext or in
>   toast . No value is obtained .. The changed code is edited in the
>   question asked ..Please help :)

---

I think you are getting keys/value mixed up when using them for JSON and INTENTS.

eg You do :-

```
public static final String TAG_NAME = "Name";
```

TAG_NAME will always have the value **Name** (that and not a name from the DB/JSON).

later you do :-

```
intent.putExtra("Name", TAG_NAME);
```

As such the intent extra with a key called **Name** will be set to the value of **TAG_NAME**, which equates to setting the value to **Name**

Rather you could use (where name is the name extracted from DB/JSON as per `String Name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);`  ):-

```
intent.putExtra("Name", name);
```

or (as TAG_NAME equates to **Name**)

```
intent.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply ... i have changed the code according to what you said but now i am getting only the key , whether in settext or in toast . No value is obtained .. The changed code is edited in the question asked ..Please help :)

Comment: When you save values to your Hashmap before list building, you might be overriding initial values already set. I would suggest creating a simple PlumberEmployee POJO and having the Hashmap key-values be Name-PlumberEmployee

Comment: What I have started doing is creating string resources with a clear name (imho) and use them for the key e.g. : `intent.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.intentkey_activitycaller), THIS_ACTIVITY + "_ADD");` where in this case R.string.intentkey is defined as `<string name="intentkey_activitycaller">CALLER</string>`. Long winded but can avoid confusion/mistyping issues. In this case THIS_ACTIVITY + "_ADD" is the value stored in the intent extra with a key **CALLER**. the retrieval is `caller = getIntent().getStringExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.intentkey_activitycaller));`

Answer (score 0):

here are what should you do in the second activity

```
 String  Name = intent.getStringExtra("Name");
        TAG_ADDRESS = intent.getStringExtra("Address");
        TAG_PINCODE = intent.getStringExtra("Pincode");
        TAG_PHONENUMBER = intent.getStringExtra("phone_number");
```

you have to use the variable value not the variable name
for example if your key is `String TAG_ADDRESS="myKey"` in the second activity you have to use `myKey` not `TAG_ADDRESS`

Comment: Thanks for the reply ... i have changed the code according to what you said but now i am getting only the key , whether in settext or in toast . No value is obtained .. The changed code is edited in the question asked.. Please help

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways in which u can achieve data in another activity first is using shared prefrence store your data selected in shared prefrence and get the data in  next activity using setter and getters.
2.You can pass data using intent
suppose i wanna pass may name using intent so i will use a key to fetch it in next activity eg.

Intent i=new(this,nextactivity.class);

i.putstring("name","tanmeet");

and now using bundle ill recover it in next activity

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

```
    String myName= extras.getString("name");
```

here name is my key

Comment: instead of using this " Intent intent = getIntent();"                                       Use Bundle to get the value like this    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();        String myName= extras.getString("name");   please vote up if you find it useful

Answer (score 0):

Just change the onItemClickListener() code.

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Plumbers.this, Plumber1.class);
                intent.putExtra("Name", personList.get(position).get(TAG_NAME));
                intent.putExtra("Address", personList.get(position).get(TAG_ADDRESS));
                intent.putExtra("Pincode", personList.get(position).get(TAG_PINCODE));
                intent.putExtra("Phone_Number", personList.get(position).get(TAG_PHONENUMBER));

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

But still you will not gt the value of address, pincode, phone number as you haven't save it in HashMap. For better help please send your json data or in order to parse json data just read address, pincode, phone number value too from json and add in hashmap before adding it in list.